# Unit testing methods with UserDefinedFunction

Tags: linq, lambda, user-defined-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have to unit test a method which is querying DocumentDb using Linq and uses one of the predefined UserDefinedFunction "IS_DEFINED". When I try to unittest this method mocking the DocumentDb part, it throws an exception "This method should only be called within Linq expression to Invoke a User-defined function".

```
public void GetRequiredData()
{
    var data = docDbClient.GetDataAsQueryable("some parameters").Where((bool)UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke("IS_DEFINED"), somefield);
}
```

GetDataAsQueryable method get the data from documentDb which I mocked but UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke throws an exception as it is not available in the unit testing scope.

How can I mock the UDF? Is there any other way I can unit test this method.

[UPDATE]

I tried using an Expression something like below

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>> expr = obj => (bool) UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke("IS_DEFINED", obj);

var data = docDbClient.GetDataAsQueryable("some parameters").Where(expr.Compile()(someobject));
```

It throws an error "Nullable object must have a value"

What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't mock UDFs through UserDefinedFunctionProvider.